# Speed up grep and writing to file

Tags: linux, bash

I would appreciate anyone's help. Currently, I have 2 files (both formatted the same) and they both have over 2 million of lines in each. Example of files below:

file 1:

```
00000001 YYYY
00000002 NYNN
00000003 YNYN
...
...
```

file 2:

```
00000001 YYNY
00000002 NYNN
00000003 YNYN
...
...
```

So notice the first line in each file are different so I would print to file 3:

```
00000001 YYYY
```

To do the above process, I have a bash script to:

1. grep the first EIGHT characters for file 2.
2. I compare the echo/output of the grep with the line in file 1.
3. IF they are different, write the line(from file 1) to file 3.

I wanted to provide sample code but keep in mind, I just made this up on the fly BUT its the same concept as my script. Currently, I am 24 hours in and only on line 240k out of 2 million. How can I speed this up in an efficient way?

```
input="file1"
while IFS= read -r line
do
LineFromFile1=$("${echo $line}")
firstEightChars=$("${echo $line:0:8}")
if grep -q "$firstEightChars" file2; then
  $LineFoundInFile2="$(grep $firstEightCharst file2)"
  if [[ $line == $LineFoundInFile2 ]]; then
    :
  else
    echo $line >> file3
done < "$input"
```

Comment: It would be faster to sort both files, and then diff them (n*log(n)) than this method (n^2). Also, your example will not run correctly and has multiple typos, and you grep file2 twice for each match.

Comment: I think you want to look at the `comm` command.  I've never used it, but the man page says it's for "select or reject lines common to two files", which sounds like what you want

Comment: `join file1 file2 | egrep -v '( [^ ]*)\1' | cut -d' ' -f1-2` if both files are ordered on the first field.

Comment: Do both files have the same number of lines and is the first column in both files exactly identical?

Comment: @Cyrus files do NOT have same number of lines but the first column are always 8 characters.

Comment: @JCP : You are creating **2** child processes for **each single line** in `$input`. This is insane. No wonder that it takes ages to complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be *so simple* with a Python script.

Python has the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function which can be used to read and compare two files line by line.

Example Bash script:

```
echo '00000001 YYYY
00000002 NYNN
00000003 YNYN' >file1


echo '00000001 YYNY
00000002 NYNN
00000003 YNYN' >file2

python3 -c '
with open("file1") as f_1, open("file2") as f_2:
   for t in zip(f_1, f_2):
      if t[0][8:-1] != t[1][8:-1]: print(t[0])'
```

Prints:

```
00000001 YYYY
```

The advantage here (over a simple `awk` script for example) only one line of each file is in active memory - the two lines being compared.

However, Unix has other solutions to the problem described. You can also use [paste](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) and `awk`:

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '$2!=$4 {print $1 OFS $2}'
```

Or if the numbers in the first column are acting as an index, you can use [join](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) and awk:

```
join file1 file2 | awk '$2!=$3 {print $1 OFS $2}'
```

Or the [comm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) command (suppressing col 1 and col 3) if the column 1 in each file is sorted will work as well:

```
comm -1 -3 file1 file2
```

All three Unix / Linux commands / pipes produce:

```
00000001 YYYY
```